# AJAX POST with Django Rest Framework sending null values

Tags: python, ajax, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I've just started using the Django Rest Framework to develop an API for an app that I'm developing and I need to be able to use AJAX requests with it. I've followed the documentation and I am able to perform any operation using the browsable api with no problems, however, my AJAX requests are not working correctly. The request is being made, but all of the values sent are `null`.

I'm stumped as to why it's not working correctly. Hopefully one of you fine lads can help me out.

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.http import Http404

from manager.models import UserProfile, Project
from manager.serializers import UserProfileSerializer, ProjectSerializer

class UserProfileList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    Returns a list of all UserProfiles
    """
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

class UserProfileDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a UserProfile instance.
    """
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

class ProjectView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    Returns a list of all Projects
    """
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer

class ProjectDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a Project instance
    """
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
```

My serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from manager.models import UserProfile, Project

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for UserProfile objects
    """
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('user', 'job_title', 'company', 'is_manager')

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for Project objects
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('created_by', 'name', 'description', 'date_created', 'icon')
```

My forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class NewProjectForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=155, widget=forms.TextInput(
                                    attrs={
                                        'placeholder': 'Assign a name to your project',
                                        'class': 'text-input m-b-5',
                                    }
                                ))
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=140, widget=forms.TextInput(
                                    attrs={
                                        'placeholder': 'Give some details about the project',
                                        'class': 'text-input m-b-2'
                                    }
                                ))
```

The relevant JS code:

```
function create_project() {
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/v1/projects/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            name: $('#id_project_name').val(), 
            description: $('#id_project_description').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken
        },
        success: function(json) {
            $('#id_project_name').val('');
            $('#id_project_description').val('');
        },
        error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Woops. The input id's are incorrect. It's meant to be `#id_name` and `#id_description` instead of `#id_project_name` and `#id_project_description`.

I guess that's what happens when you don't update **ALL** of your code when you change something.